# Bootstrap4 theming

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i have a question about extending Bootstrap4.

According to  [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults)  i have to put the BS-variables in the end of my file.

so my (scss) file looks like:

```
$color1: #f0f0f0;
$padding-left: 16px;

$primary: $333;

@import "variables";
```

But in this case i cant use any bootstrap variables, for example the spacing array or the other color-values (secondary, success, ...).

So if i want to use some BS-variables i need to import bootstrap first.

If i do so, then bootstrap is using **his** "*$primary*" value and ignores my own, because it is declared later.

I hope you understand my concern. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: They say it quite clearly: ***"Copy and paste variables as needed, modify their values, and remove the !default flag"***. Find where BS is setting the variables you want to change, copy that code into yours and change them as desired. BS won't set any already set variable.

Comment: But then I have a doubling of almost all variable, is there no better implementation? :-/

Comment: SASS doesn't run when your page loads. It runs once when you compile, and outputs your minimized and highly efficient CSS, where nothing is doubled. The default values are just that: a set of defaults that get applied if not already set.

Comment: yeah, sure - i know that.
but now I have in worst case in my variables.scss the same number of lines as in bootstraps variables. 
My question / idea was how I can avoid this duplication within the scss.

Comment: I can't stop by ask: why are you overwriting all of Bootstrap and not just what you want to change? And, since you seem to want to change all of it, why are you so upset about the amount of lines? You'd have written them anyway!